# jQuery mimic hover affect on click and remove hover affect when clicking another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, tooltip

I'm trying to make the tooltip stay when a user clicks (selecs) a box and it should hide when another box is clicked.

To better understand, this should work like like selectable options which has a tooltip, the tooltip should stay when the user clicks (selects an option), and when another box is clicked **only** the other box tooltip should stay.

The way I made the tootip stay is by declaring

```
  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).mouseover();
  })
```

But it sounds like there is no way to remove it from an element once I declared it, so the tooltip never hides.

See my full snippet below:

```js
jQuery(".box").tooltip();

jQuery(".box").click(function(){
  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).mouseover();
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
  background-color: lightpink;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box" title="box 1"></div>
<div class="box" title="box 2"></div>
<div class="box" title="box 3"></div>
<div class="box" title="box 4"></div>
<div class="box" title="box 5"></div>
<div class="box" title="box 6"></div>
```

Comment: Here's an idea... just take the `:hover` to another class and `toggle` that class on demand. BTW, to remove the class you could `$('.box').removeClass('toolTipClass'); $(this).addClass('toolTipClass');` in your `.box` click event

Comment: This does not work with classes, It is a **tooltip** which only shows on `mouseover`

Comment: jQuery UI has a [tooltip widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) that works pretty well. You can prevent it from closing by opening it from it's close method `close:function() {$(this).tooltip('open');}`. Then you can close it with `$(selector).tooltip('close')`. Maybe your libraries have something similar.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode I'll have the same issue I currently have - When I try to close the tooltip with `$(selector).tooltip('close')` it will not close because I previously declared `close:function() {$(this).tooltip('open');}` which will open the tooltip every time I try to close it

Comment: In the jQuery tooltip each tooltip gets a class of `ui-tooltip`. So when one gets stuck open I just use `$('.ui-tooltip').remove()`. If you have some sort of unique identifier this might work for you.